# How to persist the editor input in e4

Tags: eclipse, editor, eclipse-rcp, e4

In eclipse 3 there was the `EditorInput` which managed the persistence of editors and its input, but how to manage this with eclipse e4 where editors and views pretty much the same thing ...
Is there any recommended way of doing this or do I have to implemented some kind of editor input registry where I map all editor input objects to some kind of unique key and then after restarting the application I retrieve the editor input object from this registry via the key?
I've seen that I can only put strings into the persisted state of a MPart ...

Comment: Do you need something more than described here: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Eclipse4Services/article.html#eclipse4editor_persist ?

Comment: @MrCovex No that's not exactly I was looking for ... I think I haven't formulated the question precisely enough ... I'm not looking for persisting the changes made on the object being edited, rather than persist the object when the application is shut down, so that after restarting the application the input of the editor is still there ... Because right now when I restart the application and there were open editors the editor input is gone and I just see a lot of empty editors ...

Comment: Everything depends on the input of the editor. I use EMF persistance (for EMF models, of course).

Answer (score 2):

The `getPersistedState()` method of any `MApplicationElement` (which include `MPart`) returns a `Map` where you can store any string data that you want to be persisted.

If you want to save objects you will have to use the state location for your plugin in the workspace .metadata. Get the location of that with:

```java
IPath stateLoc = Platform.getStateLocation(bundle);
```

The path will usually be `.metadata/.plugins/<your plugin id>`. You can put anything you like it this area, but it is up to you to manage it.

You can use the `@Persist` annotation to get a method run when a part needs to be persisted:

```java
@Persist
void persist()
{
   ... save data 
}
```

The persisted state data is saved in the workspace .metadata and only cleared if you specify the `-clearPersistedState` option when starting your RCP.

Comment: Hmm I'm not sure, but as far as I can see I can only store Strings in the persisted state but no objects ...
`Map<String, String> org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.MApplicationElement.getPersistedState()`

Comment: Added some info about the state location where you can store objects.

Comment: After much investigation I finally came to this answer and like @tom1991te, I'm surprised there are no built-in capabilities to save EMF objects

Comment: Did you mean the `@PersistState` annotation for this purpose?

Comment: @Campa I think the question was asking about saving edit data which you would do with `@Persist`. `@PersistState` is intended for application model related state information.